# Partition of a set of integers into subsets where the max. of the subset-sums is minimum

Tags: permutations, partition-problem, combinatorics, subset-sum

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ positive integers, and $p$ be a partition of $S$ into $m$ mutually disjoint subsets, such that no subset contains more than $k$ elements.

- Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of all partitions $p$.
- Let $sum\{A\}$ denote the sum of all elements of the integer-set $A$.

Problem: Given $S$, $m$ and $k$, determine: $min_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\{max\{sum(A)|A\in p\}\}.$

I tend to believe that the above problem has a very strong similarity with the knapsack problem, and therefore, is unlikely to have a poly-time solution.

Comment: It's a variation of the optimization version of the partition problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem.

Comment: Specifically when $m=2$ and $k=n$ this is the optimization version of the (NP-hard) partition problem.